# C#: How can I loop through all resource strings?

Tags: resource-files

Assuming I can easily retrieve a string from the resouce file using this:

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:MyKey", "MyResources", (uint) CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.LCID)
```

How can I loop through all resource string entries (key and value) of the current culture?

I want to do this because I want to transfer all resource strings to the client side using an ashx-handler. If there is a more elegant way, please let me know!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the OOTB `ScriptResx` handler already in SharePoint, how is outlined here

[Chuvash - ScriptResx in SharePoint](https://chuvash.eu/2012/02/13/scriptresx-ashx-in-sharepoint/) and here [Chuvash - Javascript localization in SharePoint](https://chuvash.eu/2013/02/01/javascript-localization-in-sharepoint/)

Basically you need to add something like this in your resx-files, to create a namespace for your resource

```
<resheader name="classFullName">
  <value>Takana.Res</value>
</resheader>
```

And then you can get the resources loaded on a page through the following

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="/_layouts/ScriptResx.ashx?culture=" + L_Menu_LCID + "&name=Takana">
</script>
```

And access your resources in JS through `var lang = Takana.Res.YourResourceStringKey;`

Comment: Strange, googling for days and never stumbled upon this handler! But: Tried it and it unfortunately gives me an error 500. Tried with parameters, without, with correct name and lcid, on different site collection, server root, subsites. Always 500.

Comment: Should not give you a 500, have you tried with one of the built in resource files? like `/_layouts/ScriptResx.ashx?culture=en-us&name=SP.Res`?

Comment: It works with built-in resource files! Thanks! Too bad it does not work with culture-invariant resource files, which was the cause for my 500 error

Comment: Ah, that's right, you need to have at least an 'en-us' one you can point at